# how to generate json string with an integer as key?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I want to generate json string like this in C# language

```
{
  "error": "0",
  "message": "messages",
  "data": {
    "version": "sring",
    "1": [
      {
        "keyword": "",
        "title": ""
      },
      {
        "keyword": "",
        "title": ""
      }
    ],
    "2": [
      ...
    ],
    "3": [
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

there is a problem here, **"1":[{},{}]**,how to generate this part? I'm using asp.net mvc project by the way, I want to return this json string to the client web browser.

Comment: Any specific reason you want them to be 1,2,3 etc?

Comment: i think newtonsoft.json dll helps..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This response can be simply generated using `Dictionary<string, object>` with arrays as values.

```
public class KeywordTitle
{
    public string keyword { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public string error { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> data { get; set; }
}

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> {
    {"version", "sring"}
};

dictionary.Add("1", new []
{
    new KeywordTitle { keyword = "", title = "" },
    new KeywordTitle { keyword = "", title = "" },
    new KeywordTitle { keyword = "", title = "" }
});

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Response
{
    error = "0",
    message = "messages",
    data = dictionary
});
```

It generates:

```
{
    "error" : "0",
    "message" : "messages",
    "data" : {
        "version" : "sring",
        "1" : [{
                "keyword" : "",
                "title" : ""
            }, {
                "keyword" : "",
                "title" : ""
            }, {
                "keyword" : "",
                "title" : ""
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If it is your API, then it is a good idea to extract `version` in order to make all objects in `data` be of the same type, and keys of type `int`.

Comment: Thank you very much Yeldar, great idea. I'll take your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Get the [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) from `NuGet`. Then, in your `MVC` model use this `data annotation` on your Array property

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName="1")]
public string[] YourProperty { get; set }
```

The `PropertyName` value is used when you serialize data to `JSON`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package, serializing a `Dictionary<int, List<MyClass>>` will get you what you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and add the following attribute to the properties you what to modify the name of:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "1")]
public List<ObjectName> Objects { get; set; }
```

For more information have a look at the [serialization attributes](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm).